# Unable to access static variable in some other activity class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have an activity `MainACtivity.kt`, and i created a companion object like following to create static variable.

```
   companion object {
        var myStr:String?= null
    }
```

Now i want to use `myStr` in some activity, but its saying that `myStr has private access`

I am accessing it like following.

```
class SecondActivity: BaseActivity{

 MainActivity.myStr // myStr has private access

}
```

Comment: Show your proper code. Include the code that is only relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear, it says `Execting member declaration`.
Once you actually declare a member it works just fine:

```
class MainActivity() {
    companion object {
        var myStr: String? = null
    }
}

class SecondActivity {
    val notPrivate = MainActivity.myStr

    //otherwise you can declare a function to access myStr. It just does not work directly inside a class or a file. 
    fun bar(){
        MainActivity.myStr = "i'm not private either"
    }    
}
```